# Sending Email after sending data to database

Tags: php, html-email

Kindly seeking your help with the below code:

```
if( !$error ) {

        move_uploaded_file($file_loc,$folder.$file);

        $cuser = $userRow['userName'];
        $res = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE userId=".$_SESSION['user']);
        $userRow = mysql_fetch_array($res);

        $query = "INSERT INTO postoffers(postedby,reqName,reqEmail,reqHotel,reqOutlet,reqCnum,reqPostType,reqPostHead,reqPostDet,offerStarts,offerEnds,file,type,size) VALUES('$cuser','$rname','$remail','$rhotel','$routlet','$rcnum','$rposttype','$rposthead','$rpostdet','$rbdate','$redate','$file','$file_type','$file_size')";

        $res = mysql_query($query);

        if ($res) {
            $errTyp = "success";
            $errMSG = "Successfully Posted!";
            unset($rname);
            unset($remail);
            unset($rhotel);
            unset($routlet);
            unset($rcnum);
            unset($rposttype);
            unset($rposthead);
            unset($rpostdet);
            unset($rbdate);
            unset($redate);
            unset($file);

            $to = ;
            $subject = "Your Post Offer";   
            $message = "Thank you " . $cuser . " for the Post Request.";
            $headers = 'From: AFP Webmaster' . "\r\n" .
            $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n" .
            $headers = "Content-type:text/html;charset=iso-8859-1" . "\r\n" .
                        'Reply-To: AFP Webmaster' . "\r\n" .
                       'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

            mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

        }

        else {
            $errTyp = "danger";
            $errMSG = "Something went wrong, try again later...";
        }   

    }
```

The code WORKS PERFECTLY on the following:
1. Storing the value on DB.
2. If i place a valid email like "name@gmail.com" in $to

What I want to happen now is assigning the value of the "reqEmail" from the database or the value from the textfield "remail" to $to.

So the email will go to the email who filled up the form.

i hope i made myself clear and understandable.

Thanks!

Comment: So what's wrong with this `mail($remail, $subject, ...);` ?

Comment: theres nothing wrong.. but i just dont know how to place the value of "reqEmail" fr the DB or the value fr the textfield "$remail" to $to = ; . coz if i make it like "$to = "myname@yahoo.com"; it works perfectly.

Comment: You don't have to fetch the email again from the DB, just do `$to = $remail;` and send the mail to the recipient.

Comment: i did that before and it doesn't work. but then again i realized, i have to move this down: unset($rname);
            unset($remail);
            unset($rhotel);
            unset($routlet);
            unset($rcnum);
            unset($rposttype);
            unset($rposthead);
            unset($rpostdet);
            unset($rbdate);
            unset($redate);
            unset($file);

below my email section.. and it works!

thank @RajdeepPaul for the time. *peace

Comment: Glad that your issue is now resolved. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You're clearing your variables **before** sending the email, so PHP doesn't know where to send the email to. You need to place your "unset" functions after the PHP Mailer call. Try this:

```
if (!$error) {
    move_uploaded_file($file_loc, $folder.$file);

    $cuser = $userRow['userName'];
    $res = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE userId=".$_SESSION['user']);
    $userRow = mysql_fetch_array($res);

    $query = "INSERT INTO postoffers(postedby,reqName,reqEmail,reqHotel,reqOutlet,reqCnum,reqPostType,reqPostHead,reqPostDet,offerStarts,offerEnds,file,type,size) VALUES('$cuser','$rname','$remail','$rhotel','$routlet','$rcnum','$rposttype','$rposthead','$rpostdet','$rbdate','$redate','$file','$file_type','$file_size')";
    $res = mysql_query($query);

    if ($res) {
        $to = ;
        $subject = "Your Post Offer";
        $message = "Thank you " . $cuser . " for the Post Request.";
        $headers = 'From: AFP Webmaster' . "\r\n".
        $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n".
        $headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=iso-8859-1" . "\r\n" . 'Reply-To: AFP Webmaster' . "\r\n" . 'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
        mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

        $errTyp = "success";
        $errMSG = "Successfully Posted!";
        unset($rname);
        unset($remail);
        unset($rhotel);
        unset($routlet);
        unset($rcnum);
        unset($rposttype);
        unset($rposthead);
        unset($rpostdet);
        unset($rbdate);
        unset($redate);
        unset($file);
    } else {
        $errTyp = "danger";
        $errMSG = "Something went wrong, try again later...";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much!! :)